# How to get IPv4 when device is connected to mobile data

Tags: android, ipv6, ipv4

When I try to get the device IP with mobile data it always returns IPv6, but when I use wifi it gives IPv4. How can I get IPv4 in both conditions?
Here is my code for IP address.

From MainActivity, I call this method.

```
Map<String,Object> header =new  HashMap<String,Object>();

new WebService(this).callGetMethod("https://wtfismyip.com/text",header,this);
```

In WebService Class.

```
public void callGetMethod(String path, Map<String, Object> header, final WSResponse objWsResponse) {

        this.objWsResponse = objWsResponse;

        Call<ResponseBody> call = ApiClient.getClient().create(DemoInterface.class).getDemoData(path, header);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

                String result = null;
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    try {
                        result = response.body().string();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else if (response.code() == 403) {
                    try {
                        result = response.errorBody().string();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else if (response.code() == 426) {
                    try {
                        result = response.errorBody().string();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(activity, Class.forName("com.exaple.example.ui.demoActivity"));
                        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        activity.startActivity(intent);
                        activity.finish();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    try {
                        result = response.errorBody().string();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                objWsResponse.onSuccess(result, response.code());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                objWsResponse.onFailure(call.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Your app needs to be able to handle IPv6. When using 4G LTE, your connection will usually be via IPv6. Even if the phone has IPv4 it will be double or triple NATted and cannot accept incoming connections, so knowing the global IPv4 address is generally useless.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I use IPv4 for to get country from API so in this situation IPv6 in not working. Can you please suggest me which is the alternative way to get country?

Comment: You pass the IPv6 address to your API provider. If they don't provide any data, then find a different provider.